# How can I setTimeout my recursive function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show the process of how the backtracking algorithm solves a sudoku board, but I'm not sure how I can make sure that it only gets called every 500ms.

```
function solveBoard(board) {
// I tried doing setTimeout from here to the bottom, but it breaks the solver and just puts 9s everywhere.
    let empty = findEmpty(board);
    if (!empty) return true;
    let row = empty[0];
    let col = empty[1];
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) { 
        board[row][col] = i;
        console.log(board[row][col]);
        document.getElementById(`${row}-${col}`).value = i;
        if (checkValid(board, row, col)) {
            if (solveBoard(board)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        board[row][col] = 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The first time I call solve board is just an event listener.

```
solveBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    solveBoard(boardArray);
});
```

Comment: Did you try the [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method?

Answer (score 0):

Call `sleep` in `solveBoard`

```js
async function solveBoard(board) {
   await sleep()
   // …
}

function sleep(ms = 500) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
    
// Demo
(async () => {
  console.log('a')
  await sleep()
  console.log('b')
  await sleep()
  console.log('c')
})();
```